# The Monopoly tournament's secret prize

Tags: word, story, metapuzzles

The image below is the aftermath of a secret tournament of Monopoly played here on PSE.
Akin to something that might come out of a subreddit like [r/anarchychess](https://www.reddit.com/r/AnarchyChess/), the board has been massively scrambled and edited due to the immeasurable amount of homebrew rules and mechanics.
The only thing more secret than the tournament itself was the prize for winning.
**What is the tournament's prize?**

[image: No secrets here!]

> **AUTHOR'S NOTES:**
> This story is fictional, there was no actual Monopoly tournament.
> Some tags have been left out on purpose and will be added as information is discovered.
> There's quite a bit here to unpack, good luck!
> I'm also going to mention that partial answers are completely acceptable!
> (It also helps give me an idea on where people are stuck so I can give better hints. Thanks!)

**Hint the First:**

> It looks like it's *a bit off... center*.
>  And maybe other places as well...

**Edit the First**

> The [steganography](/questions/tagged/steganography) tag has been replaced with the [metapuzzles](/questions/tagged/metapuzzles) tag to avoid some confusion and give a hint.

**Edit the Second**

> The third yellow property has been changed to avoid ambiguity.

**Edit the Third**

> The first yellow property has been changed. I should have double checked these ones before posting, sorry about all the changes.

**Hint the Second**

> You might want a *best friend*...
>  Being stuck is quite *taxing*...

**Hint the Third**

> *YLW*

Comment: I can trade the pink (have) for the identity of the guy in the chest (want)

Comment: @Amoz Sorry, not really a fair deal. I'll give you the high-res version, though. *Hands you https://i.stack.imgur.com/qF09F.png*

Comment: I guess my deal's off, op is handing it out free, hooray!

Comment: Great puzzle so far, I'm making decent progress I think. rot13(Vf gurer n snvag vzntr va gur Punapr qenj cvyr va gur zvqqyr bs gur obneq, fvzvyne gb gur snvag bhgyvarf va gur Punapr fcnprf? Vg frrzf yvxr gurer'f fbzrguvat gurer ohg V pna'g znxr vg bhg. V gevrq fbzr fvzcyr fghss yvxr vapernfvat gur pbagenfg ohg V jnfa'g ernyyl noyr gb znxr vg nal pyrnere. Be nz V whfg frrvat guvatf?)

Comment: @SQLnoob rot13(Lrf, gurer vf n cvpgher gurer, ohg vg vf abg rffragvny gb svthevat vg bhg. Guvax bs vg nf nabgure uvag. Vs lbh'q yvxr n qnexre irefvba, urer vg vf: uggcf://v.fgnpx.vzthe.pbz/i1qT1.wct)

Comment: @WoomyRogue thanks! I saw your edit to the Author's notes, so I added a partial answer to keep track of my progress so far.

Comment: @WoomyRogue thanks for the new hints. I had to give my brain a break from this one for a day or two! rot13(Fbzrguvat jvgu qvnzbaqf? "Gnkvat" - vapbzr gnk unf n qvnzbaq funcr ba vg; yhkhel gnk unf pbyberq qvnzbaqf ba gur evat. "Obgu jnlf" = hfr gur pbyberq cebcregvrf va gur beqre gurl'er qvfcynlrq ba gur evat sebz evtug gb yrsg naq yrsg gb evtug? "orfg sevraq" = qvnzbaqf ner n tvey'f orfg sevraq; LYJ = "lbhe ybivat jvsr"?  Gur cuenfr RATNTRZRAG EVAT whzcrq bhg ng zr - vg'f 14 yrggref naq unf n ybg bs yrggref va pbzzba jvgu fbzr bs gur nafjref V nyernql unir ohg V pna'g znxr n pbaarpgvba gb vg.)

Comment: I've had no luck rot13(trggvat gur uvqqra grkg gb fubj hc. V nffhzr vg qvssref sebz gur onpxtebhaq ol "n ovg" be gjb. Pbhyq gung qvfgvapgvba unir tbggra ybfg jura vzthe pbairegrq gur vzntr gb n wct?)

Comment: @cap That is likely the reason why you're having trouble. In testing I was able to see the text by reducing the saturation and applying multiple brightness changes. Judging by the answers below others were able to find this text as well.

Comment: @WoomyRogue that helped. Previously I was just trying to using fill to isolate them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The full solution (many thanks to @WoomyRogue for the excellent puzzle and hints, and to commenters @samm82, @Amoz, @Stiv, @cap and anyone I missed for contributing to the solution with their brilliant insights):

The Center of the Board:

> There's a bunch of text faintly in the blank areas in the center of the board. It appears to say: 
> ALL SOLUTIONS ARE AN ENGLISH WORD
> IGNORE THE FOUR CORNERS
> BE SURE TO GO IN ORDER
> ONLY USE EACH COLOR ONCE

Community Chest Draw Pile:

> The space for the deck of Community Chest cards is surrounded by [morse code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_code). It decodes to **ANSWER IS FOURTEEN LETTERS**.

Chance Draw Pile:

> The morse code around the Chance pile decodes to **LOOK AT SETS OF PROPERTIES**.

The Four Railroads:

> The railroad property spaces are surrounded by railroad tracks, which led me to believe the letters in place of their property names formed a [Rail Fence Cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rail_fence_cipher). Taking them in order around the board we have DSGTNASHLSARDLWTOMLECIOK which decodes to DNDCLASSWITHGLOOMSTALKER. The D&D Class with a Gloom Stalker subclass is the **RANGER.**

The Two Utilities:

> The space normally named Electric Company says TEA CIRCLE COPY MEGAN which anagrams to ELECTRIC COMPANY AGE. The space for Waterworks says STRAW NETWORK which anagrams to WATERWORKS NT. The leftover letters spell **AGENT.**

The Community Chest Spaces:

> The items in the chests around the board are: a capital Greek letter Delta, the flag of India, the singer Romeo Santos, and the character Echo from the video game Overwatch. These are all characters in the [NATO phonetic alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO_phonetic_alphabet): delta = D, India = I, Romeo = R, Echo = E. So this results in **DIRE.**

The Chance Spaces:

> The three spaces contain faint outlines of a leaf, a crab, and a monkey, to the right of a question mark. The word that can fit in _leaf, _crab, and _monkey is **SPIDER**.

Luxury Tax:

> Luxury tax has colored gems in this order: orange, yellow, green, blue, red, purple (pink?). The price has changed to PAY 1/2, and there is a faint number 1 in the upper left hand corner of the space. The gems on this space look like Marvel's Infinity Stones, with the largest blue stone representing **SPACE**.

Income Tax:

> Income tax has a 2, and arrows pointing left and right with the text "BOTH WORK". There is a diamond shape in the center that is identical to two diamond shapes in the middle of the board. Those two diamonds are adjacent to the words "FAST" and "GAME", so we should take the second letter of either of those words which gives us the answer **A**.

The Brown Properties:

> The prices of these properties have changed from 60 to 83 and 76. The [atomic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chemical_elements) 83 and 76 represent the elements Bismuth (Bi) and Osmium (Os) respectively. **BIOS**

The Light Blue Properties:

> Conspicuously has two red hotels aligned vertically on Oriental Ave. Also two of the black line segments are missing from Connecticut Ave, and Oriental Ave has an extra black line segment at the bottom.
>
> The black lines and red hotels form a [Pigpen Cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigpen_cipher) which, when read across the top and then across the bottom, spells out the word **BENIGN**.

The Pink Properties:

> “Mirrored France” - the horizontal reflection of the flag of France is the [signal flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_maritime_signal_flags) for the letter T (TANGO). Looking at other signal flags, the bottom 2/3 of the flag of Russia represents the letter E (ECHO) and a “Blue Chessboard” represents the letter N (NOVEMBER). So for this set of properties the answer is **TEN**.

The Orange Properties:

> The only thing unusual about these is their prices.  730, 915, and 700 look suspiciously like times on a clock. Also the signal flags in the prior property group made me think of [flag semaphore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_semaphore), which uses red and yellow (i.e. orange?) colored flags held in different positions to convey letters of the alphabet. With arms in the position of 7:30, this signals the letter A. 9:15 signals the letter R, and 7:00 signals K. **ARK**

The Red Properties:

> Once again the only thing unusual here is the prices. We have 626, 478, and 5283. I thought this looked like a phone number. 626-478-5283. If I look at a [phone keypad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_keypad) and try to convert numbers to letters, I found that this phone number corresponds to the word **MANIPULATE.**

The Yellow Properties:

> Sancerre is a region of France. Hyderabad is a city in India. Lessing-Straße appears to clue to Germany. F + I + G = **FIG**

The Green Properties:

> There are a few things going on here. The names of the properties have been truncated; the prices have been changed to single digits, and there are faint images of a capital letter T, and downward pointing arrow, and a stylized ampersand.
>
> Penn & = TELLER; North with a down arrow = SOUTH; Pacific T = ??. Taking the letter from the position indicated by the price gives **THE**.

The Dark Blue Properties:

> The only thing changed here are the prices. We have 2111 and 1344. The prices are [Tap Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tap_code) representing the word **FACT**.

Putting it all together:

> The number of green houses indicates which letter to take from the answer for that set of properties (and for the light blue properties, 1 red hotel = 5 green houses). For the non-colored property groups, we count how many of that property type appear on the board and take the letter in that position. Taking them in the order in which we first encounter them, starting from GO and moving clockwise around the board:
>
> Brown (1) BIOS = **B**
>  Community Chest (3) DIRE = **R**
>  Income Tax (1) **A**
>  Railroads (4) RANGER = **G**
>  Light Blue (5) BENIGN = **G**
>  Chance (3) SPIDER = **I**
>  Pink (3) TEN = **N**
>  Utilities (2) AGENT = **G**
>  Orange (2) ARK = **R**
>  Red (3) MANIPULATE = **N** (probably should be **I**)
>  Yellow (3) FIG = **G**
>  Green (2) THE = **H**
>  Dark Blue (4) FACT = **T**
>  Luxury Tax (1) SPACE = **S**
>
> So the prize for winning the tournament is **BRAGGING RIGHTS!**

Comment: rot13(Nyy bs lbhe nafjref fb sne ner pbeerpg! Gurer vf bar xrl cvrpr bs vasbezngvba gung lbh'er zvffvat (frr Uvag #1 sbe n pyhr); vg zvtug uryc jvgu fbzr bs gur nzovthbhf nafjref naq gur svany fbyhgvba!)

Comment: rot13(Fyvtug punatr sebz gur cerivbhf pbzzrag: Ivrjvat gur obneq sebz gur cebcre fvqr vf gur jnl gb tb.)

Comment: @WoomyRogue Thank you, I've edited in that new information to my partial solution above. I'll continue to work on it.

Comment: Brown: rot13(ngbzvp ahzoref -> OVBF); Light Blue: Cvtcra pvcure (gbc ebj, gura obggbz ebj) -> ORAVTA; Green: Craa (&) GRYYRE, Abegu (↓) FBHGU, Cnpvsvp (G) NGYNAGVP? TERRAJVPU? GENADHVY? GEHPHYRAG? gnxr gur agu yrggre jurer a vf gur pbfg tvirf GUV be GUR?; Dark Blue: xabpx/gnc pbqr -> SNPG; Luxury Tax: trz pbybhef zngpu gur Vasvavgl Fgbarf; pbhyq or GUNABF be FCNPR (gur oyhr fgbar gung vf rzcunfvmrq)

Comment: rot13(Whfg gb nqq n pbhcyr enaqbz vqrnf V unq: 
Punapr: ? pbhyq pyhr fvatyr yrggre; YRNS/PENO/URNQ funer yrggre N va pbzzba, punapr pneq ybbxf fyvtugyl yvxr n fxrjrq nycun (be znlor abg)
Lryybj: Pbhagel pbqrf NHG/VAQ/SEN nantenz gb NAGVSENHQ)

Comment: rot13(Nyy ner pbeerpg rkprcg sbe lryybj! Urer ner fbzr fznyyre uvagf: 
Gur gjb gnkrf ner frcnengr chmmyrf. Sbe Yhkhel Gnk tb ybbx ng Uvag #1 ntnva.
Lbh'er ba gur evtug genpx sbe lryybj, whfg n qvssrerag jnl bs qrpbqvat.
Nf sbe gur punapr fcnprf, abgr gur vzntr'f cbfvgvba gb gur "?".
Lbh'er fhcre pybfr, xrrc hc gur terng jbex!)

Comment: @WoomyRogue Thanks for the hints, I've made a few more edits. I feel like we're getting close but a few parts are still escaping me.  I'll keep thinking!

Comment: Pretty sure that rot13(Gur 'urnq' ba Punapr vf n zbaxrl. Guhf lbh unir FCVQRE cynag, FCVQRE peno naq FCVQRE zbaxrl...)

Comment: rot13(V zrffrq hc zl cerivbhf uvag, v zrnag gb fnl Vapbzr Gnk vafgrnq bs Yhkhel Gnk. Yhkhel Gnk vf pbeerpg!
YLJ vf abg na npebalz, lbh ner rkgerzryl pybfr sbe Lryybj, lbh whfg arrq n *yratgu* bs gvzr gb svther vg bhg...)

Comment: @WoomyRogue I updated the answer for yellow, is that correct? Is the third hint YLW or LYW? (You typed it both ways in different places). I think I need another hint, I feel like I have a lot of info but not sure what to do with it... and still no idea what to do with Income Tax...

Comment: I reckon yellow might possibly represent a three-letter fruit made of the initials of the three countries... (or its reverse, since that's the order of the properties)

Comment: rot13(Gur uvag vf LYJ, fbeel sbe nal glcbf. Lbhe pheerag nafjre vf abg pbeerpg (nygubhtu n cbffvoyr fbyhgvba V snvyrq gb guvax bs!) ohg lbh ner fhcre qhcre pybfr. Nf sbe Vapbzr Gnk, ybbx ng Uvag 1... naq gura Uvag 1 ntnva.) Let me know if you need more help!

Comment: rot13(Guvf vfa'g gbb vzcbegnag, ohg sbe Cnpvsvp Nirahr, gur G frrzf gb ercynpr gur jbeq nirahr, fb vs vg vf n 'ebnq', vg ybbxf yvxr na Vagrefrpgvba, juvpu jbhyq tvir R sbe yrggre 7.)

Comment: For Income Tax rot13(znlor gur cevpr bs gjb vaqvpngrf gur yrggre gb rkgenpg sebz gur fbyhgvba jbeq. Gur jbeqf "OBGU JBEX" zvtug zrna gung gurer ner gjb jbeqf gung unir gur fnzr frpbaq yrggre. Znlor gur jbeqf OBGU JBEX gurzfryirf tvivat hf gur yrggre B...)

Comment: @cap, if that's the case, I had a similar idea for Luxury Tax where rot13(vs gur fvk trzfgbarf pyhr GUNABF, cynpvat n yrggre va rnpu chgf A va gur rzcunfvmrq trz, juvpu pbhyq or vgf yrggre?)

Comment: @samm82 I think OP confirmed that rot13(gur pbeerpg nafjre sbe Yhkhel Gnk vf FCNPR. )

Comment: @WoomyRogue I've added a new section to my answer at the bottom, mostly to keep track of all the info I have and my thoughts... care to review and give another hint or a steer in the right direction?  I know you've mentioned a few times to look at Hint 1 again but so far I don't know what to do with it unfortunately.

Comment: Luxury Tax: rot13(FCNPR vf vaqrrq gur pbeerpg nafjre.)
Income Tax: rot13(Gur qvnzbaq vf xrl. Abg bayl vf vg va gur pragre bs gur fcnpr, vgf va gur pragre bs gur obneq nf jryy.)
Yellows: rot13(SVT vf pbeerpg! Gurer jnf cebonoyl n orggre jnl gb vaqvpngr n fvatyr yrggre sbe rnpu fcnpr, fbeel sbe abg gnxvat bgure ynathntr/pbhagel nooerivngvbaf vagb pbafvqrengvba.)

Comment: @WoomyRogue Ah! Hmm ok... rot13(Fb vs V ybbx ng gur gjb zngpuvat qvnzbaq funcrf va gur pragre bs gur obneq, gurl'er nqwnprag gb gur jbeqf SNFG naq TNZR.  Naq gur 2 vaqvpngrf V jnag gur frpbaq yrggre, fb gur nafjre sbe Vapbzr Gnk vf gur yrggre N (fvapr "obgu jbex")?)

Comment: rot13(*tvirf lbh n guhzof-hc* Bar zber fgrc gb tb!)

Comment: For sets without houses, rot13(Gur yrggre rkgenpgvba vf gur ahzore bs fdhnerf va gung frg. Gur nafjre vf OENTTVATEVTUGF. Abg fher jung'f hc jvgu erq gubhtu.)

Comment: Forgot to mention rot13(Gur beqre vf gur beqre lbh rapbhagre gurz hfvat gurz bayl gur svefg gvzr.)

Comment: @cap just beat me to it!  I've cleaned up the answer now to get rid of all the interim thoughts.

Comment: Whelp, sorry about the error with the Reds.
Congrats! *confetti*
So many comments and hints but that's not a bad thing! Thanks to all who helped!
This was the biggest puzzle I've made by far (not that I've made much lol) and I'm happy to see it solved!

Comment: It was awesome, a lot of fun to solve and very rewarding to finally put all the pieces together. Thanks!

Comment: To clarify the Greens rot13(Gur svefg terra cebcregl jnf gur uneqrfg gb pbzr hc jvgu n jbeq sbe, gur "G" jnf zrnag gb ercerfrag Gurfnhehf.pbz, jurer gur svefg nagbalz sbe CNPVSVP jnf NTVGNGRQ, yrnqvat gb GUR.)